# Table doesn't recover on Chrome when resizing the screen size

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

It only happens on Chrome, and at the beginning, the table displays well. However,when I resize it into small and then change back to big screen, the table is messed up. This resizing issue make it not perfectSee the gif image and code below. Basically, I want to the table to display one element in a line when it comes to small screen. If it is a Chrome bug, is there any alternative solutions? Thanks.
[image]

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .responsive-table-md tbody td {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
I am wondering if there is way to fix it. If it is Chrome bug, is there any alternative to do the table staff.

<table class="responsive-table-md">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Test 1</th>
      <th>Test 2</th>
      <th>Test 3</th>
      <th>Test 4</th>
      <th>Test 5</th>


    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
      <td>E</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this [looks like a bug](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en).

Comment: what you're trying to achieve ? As you've set `<td>` as `block` while keeping other elements of `<table>` default properties.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Thank you for reminding. Basically, I want to the table to display one element in a line when it comes to small screen.  This resizing issue make it not perfect.

Comment: i suggest reading this, as it does not have the same issues https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Comment: @HaoyuChen If you've few tables like 5 OR 6 then you can go for the approach as *epoch* has given, otherwise keep it same as it's desktop view OR you can check [**this**](http://zurb.com/playground/projects/responsive-tables/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [article](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/), the whole set of table elements should be reset, if you only reset the `td`, chrome behaves weird.

> The biggest change is that we are going to force the table to not behave like a table by setting every table-related element to be block-level.

With the [following](http://jsfiddle.net/cetdcpoj/), it does not behave strange:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
        display: block; 
    }
}
```

Here is the complete [change](http://jsfiddle.net/cetdcpoj/1/), I slightly modified the CSS from the article.